# Responsive transparent overlapping css circles with text align vertical and center

Tags: css

Can't seem to get my text to align center and vertical within each circle. Tried putting h1 text inside of another div - display table, but having problems containing text inside each circle classe.
here is my codepen with example code?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="circle-wrapper">
<div class="circle1 transparent_class"><h1>Two lines <br />&amp;Two lines</h1></div>
<div class="circle2 transparent_class"><h1>Two lines<br /> Two lines</h1></div>
<div class="circle3 transparent_class"><h1>Two lines<br />&amp; Two lines</h1></div>
<div class="circle4 transparent_class "><h1>Two lines<br /> Two lines</h1></div>
</div><!--close of circle-wrapper-->
```

**CSS:**

```
 #circle-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    }

    .circle1, .circle2, .circle3, .circle4 {
    position:absolute;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 32%;
    height: 32%;
    padding-bottom: 32%;
    }

    h1.circle1 h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
    }

    .circle1 {
    background-color:#889fbe;
    color:000;
    margin-top:-8%;
    left:10%;
    }

    .circle2 {
    margin-top:10%;
    color:000;
    left:24%;
    background-color:#b1daf6;
    }

    .circle3 {
    margin-top:24%;
    left:10%;
    background-color:#4f4f51;
    }

    .circle4 {
    margin-top:10%;
    left:-8%;
    background-color:#56a0d3;   
    }

    .transparent_class {
    /* IE 8 */
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";

    /* IE 5-7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);

    /* Netscape */
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;

    /* Safari 1.x */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;

    /* Good browsers */
    opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/matriplett/pen/LJcnE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a wrapper `div` around your `h1`

```
    <div class="circle1 transparent_class">
<div class="wrapper"><h1>Two lines <br />&amp;Two lines</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

and change the style like this:

```
.wrapper{
  margin-top:40%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display: table;
}
```

see here for a updated pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yugBK

Comment: If this worked for you then you should accept the answer (check mark to the left) and also upvote it, so future visitors will be helped.

Comment: so now i switched it up a bit to float the repsonsive circles.. but can't seem to figure out how to stop them from being oblong. can anyone be so kind to explain. here is an updated codepen

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.. first add a circle class

```
  <div id="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle circle1 transparent_class">  
      <h1>Two lines <br />&amp;Two lines</h1>
    </div>
    etc.
```

then set a height on the containing element

```
#circle-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    height: 1200px;
}
```

and also on .circle and h1...

```
.circle, h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GnLJK